# Connect to Cassandra using pig latin using java

Tags: java, hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

Instead of using grunt, I want to write java program that uses PigServer to connect to Cassandra. Its not able to find environment variables I have set for Pig. Any kind of help is appreciated. Or if there are any better option than Pig and Java map reduce.

Here are the env variables

```
export PATH=/Users/rachana/software/pig-0.11.1/bin:$PATH
export PIG_HOME=/Users/rachana/software/pig-0.11.1
export PIG_CONF_DIR=/Users/rachana/software/hadoop-1.1.2/conf
export PIG_INITIAL_ADDRESS=localhost
export PIG_RPC_PORT=9160
export PIG_PARTITIONER=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
export PIG_OPTS=-Dudf.import.list=org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig:$PIG_OPTS
```

Code is

```
package com.chegg.hwh.tracking.dao;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage;
import org.apache.pig.ExecType;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;
import org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext;

public class HWHDataPigMapReduce {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("PIG_HOME", "/Users/rachana/software/pig-0.11.1");
    properties.put("PIG_CONF_DIR", "/Users/rachana/software/hadoop-1.1.2/conf");
    properties.put("PIG_INITIAL_ADDRESS", "localhost");
    properties.put("PIG_RPC_PORT", "9160");
    properties.put("PIG_PARTITIONER","org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner");
    PigContext pigContext = new PigContext(ExecType.LOCAL,properties);

    CassandraStorage cassandraStorage = new CassandraStorage();

    PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(pigContext);


    pigServer.registerQuery("LOAD 'cassandra://hwh_tracking/users' USING org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage();");
    pigServer.registerQuery("emailgroup = group rows by email;");
    pigServer.dumpSchema("emailgroup");


}
```

}

And error is

```
13/07/05 16:56:19 INFO executionengine.HExecutionEngine: Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///
2013-07-05 16:56:19.117 java[3413:1c03] Unable to load realm mapping info from SCDynamicStore
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/rachana/astyanax_lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/rachana/astyanax_lib/pig-0.11.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Cannot get schema from loadFunc org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1607)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1546)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:516)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:529)
    at com.chegg.hwh.tracking.dao.HWHDataPigMapReduce.main(HWHDataPigMapReduce.java:21)
Caused by: Failed to parse: Can not retrieve schema from loader org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage@beeb7e9
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:193)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1599)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not retrieve schema from loader org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage@beeb7e9
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.<init>(LOLoad.java:90)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:839)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.load_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:3236)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1315)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:799)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:517)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:392)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:184)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 2245: Cannot get schema from loadFunc org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.getSchemaFromMetaData(LOLoad.java:178)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.<init>(LOLoad.java:88)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: PIG_INPUT_INITIAL_ADDRESS or PIG_INITIAL_ADDRESS environment variable not set
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage.setLocation(CassandraStorage.java:404)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage.getSchema(CassandraStorage.java:414)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.getSchemaFromMetaData(LOLoad.java:174)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

When Pig connects to Cassandra, it does so by calling the Cassandra ColumnFamilyOutputFormat and ColumnFamilyOutputFormat classes which in turn call the Hector API's which connect to Cassandra.  If you want to write a Java program that accesses Cassandra, it would be far easier to just write to the Hector API's.  There are other Cassandra API's at that level, too, like CQL via JDBC.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I got it running by setting env variables in my eclipse -> run configurations.

Comment: @plzdontkillme how it has been solved , like i am using grunt shell and same exception coming to me .